# Older Coleman Electric Furnace Not Used

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating, furnace

My wife's family has this older Coleman electric furnace in their mobile home that is not being used, instead they use electric space heaters. We're not sure how long the furnace has been unused or why.

I have been able to turn a switch at the furnace and force it to kick on, so we at least know that it turns on. However there's been some remodeling and we can't find the thermostat to test for heat.

What can we do to test that heat can still be generated from the furnace, directly at the furnace? Is that even possible to test?

Thanks for your help.

[image: COLEMAN ELECTRIC HEATER]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be concerned about dust build up in the furnace after not being used for a long time.  The reason why it was not used might be important, odd to buy new heaters if the one there is working.

Comment: Can you add some clear, legible photos of those labels? The wiring diagram on the bottom left probably has everything you need to know on it, but while you're there you might as well snap the rest of them

Comment: Added another photo of the bottom labels. However the wiring label may still be out of focus. 

From the top photo of the furnace, is it easy to tell which might be for the hidden thermostat?

Comment: Since you can not take a clear picture, you can look for it your self on the electrical schematic. It wont give you the physical location of the thermostat, but a chance to connect 24 volt to it to start it.

Comment: @DIYDad can you get us a closeup of the wiring diagram label please?

Comment: Maybe they wanted to only heat parts of the home, creating "Zones" via space heaters.   If you want resurrect this thing, I'd take it apart enough to vacuum the fan and heater coils. You could get a cheap thermostat and connect it locally to test.  The duct-work should also be inspected.  They may be damaged or leaking, can you get under the house?  Also, they could be very filthy inside from years of non-use.  There are HVAC companies that do duct cleaning.  Sorry, but to be honest, you're looking at a renovation, not just the thermostat.

Comment: Yeah, we need a shot of that lower left diagram, full frame, and throw LOTS of light on it, borrow a desk lamp if you need to.  It's very difficult to find this in a web search - I've tried and tried. All the pages I found are either asking for it, or the wrong *brand*, or scams.  It's astoundingly scant.

Comment: @George portable space heaters would be a dumb way to do that due to their general dangerousness.  They are specifically labeled "Do not run unattended" - for a  reason!  If they wanted zone control they could install any number of perfectly safe Cadet baseboards inside the amp allocation assigned to that Coleman. Those are cheaper than space heaters by year 2 (they last 40 years, the space heaters rarely make it through a second season).   However none of it is **efficient**; I would use the Coleman's ait handling stack for an extended range heat pump.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   No arguments from me on your comment.   Just to be clear, I didn't say it was a good idea, just that the previous owners may have tried to created their own "zoned heating"  Electrical resistance heating is very very expensive, we can agree on that! Whether baseboard, space heaters, in-wall Cadets ALL cost a ton of money to run.   I do differ in that 2 types of space heaters are quite safe:  Oil filled radiator types and ones with ceramic heating elements.  The ones with Nihcrome wire that glow are very dangerous.  ... continues,,,

Comment: If the air handler is is good shape and the ductwork is in good shape, or at least repairable, a heat pump retrofit would of course provide both Heating and A/C, but a much more expensive than a cleaning and repair.   Depends upon how old the mobile home is, how long they'll stay there, etc. etc. to see if they get cost recovery or not or if they want to invest in a HP to give them A/C as well.  I still worry about the duct condition, it would have to be inspected and probably cleaned.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I disagree about safety. Yes, the ones with reachable toaster wire are the *most* dangerous. But *all* portable electric heaters generate 1500W of heat continuously in a relatively small space, so whether plain toaster, toaster + fan, oil filled, ceramic or *whatever*, the end result is that too close to curtains, blankets, etc. they **will** start a fire.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   Well, we'll have to disagree about the oil filled heaters the large radiant surface would never cause a fire.   Not even close.  The ceramic heaters are also very safe with over temp controls and tip over controls.   I grew up poor and the only source of heat in my bedroom was a portable strip heater that glowed orange when on.   Had a basketball near it one night and and it melted it.    Yeah, those are NOT SAFE!  And I still agree that even fan forced space Nihcrome wiring aren't very safe,  But also realize that most of the warning labels come from lawyers.

Comment: A picture of the main breaker panel, size of electric service and significant other loads (cooking, water heating, etc.) would be helpful. While presumably everything was sized appropriately *at one time*, I'd worry about other changes over the years relative to total electric service available. This is nominally a 60A heater - that's a *lot* of power, equivalent to running 10 standard plug-in space heaters *at the same time*.

Comment: I finally got a chance to add close ups of the circuit diagram where they can be seen clearly.

Comment: @DIYDad which cable in your first photo heads off to the thermostat?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not sure, this is my first time working with a furnace. Really just trying to learn something here. Do you think I could attach a thermostat to the thermostat wire at the furnace and get it to produce some heat by chance?

Comment: @DIYDad -- shorting the R and W connections at any thermostat that is connected should cause the thing to start heating