Breakers and Wiring for Older Coleman Furnace
I am trying to wire an Older Coleman mobile home furnace up. Model 3400318. It came with a section of 4 awg (2 leads and ground). I’m confused about what breakers to use. I’m using heat only. Do I use two 50 amp or a 60/40?




Do you want to wire it with two circuits or with one? Looks like both are options given the nameplate ratings.

You also want to make sure your electric panel can handle the extra power, unless this is just a replacement(not an addition).  It might wise to check if a mini-split would be better than paying all that money to run a big toaster(unless you like giving power company extra money).

Appliance requirements
According to the nameplate pictured, the combined heating elements in that furnace draw a total of 70.5 amps.  The blower motor adds an additional 5 amps.  You are given the option to wire it with 1 circuit (100A), or two circuits, (one 60A and one 40A).
Wiring it with a single circuit
If you want to wire it with a single circuit, you'll need:

100A 2-pole breaker
2 AWG wire (copper) or 0 AWG wire (aluminum)

If you want to use the 4 AWG cable you already have, you have to wire it with 2 circuits.
Wiring it with dual circuits
The cable you have can meet the needs of one or both depending on what its conductors are made of.  Unfortunately, the picture cuts off the part of the labeling that indicates the conductor material.
Circuit 1:

60A 2-pole breaker
4 AWG wire (copper) or 3 AWG wire (aluminum)

Circuit 2:

40A 2-pole breaker
8 AWG wire (copper) or 6 AWG wire (aluminum)

If your cable is copper you can use it for both circuits, even though it is slightly overkill for circuit 2.  If your cable is aluminum you can still use it for circuit 2, but you'll need to buy new cable for circuit 1 - either 3 AWG Al or 4 AWG Cu.

It's obviously (3) 23.5A elements - 47A ("CKT 1") divided by 2 is 23.5A, as is 28A ("CKT 2") - 5A (motor). No stages. Look at the schematic on https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/261254/older-coleman-electric-furnace-not-used which is the same heater type, just a slightly lower BTU.

@nobody  Thanks.  Edited answer accordingly.

The 4 awg was just about 4 feet they left on it when removing. I’m honestly trying to wire it the cheapest way possible for my daughter. Trying to convert from gas to electric. It’s a 200 amp box with 5 slots available.
